# 80's Young Adult Science Fiction Book With Cassette

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, audio-book

I've been searching for this for years.  I can only recall the following:

- Early 80's (possibly late 70's).
- Young adult short story book with hand drawn illustrations
- Was a book on cassette, a follow along type
- Science Fiction story that ends where the two main characters, a man and woman, are left on a new planet to populate
- A third main character is killed fighting off an attack
- The most interesting feature was the production quality - it was complete with sound effects, different voice actors, and this really haunting sci-fi score that I thought sounded very close to the Amityville Horror theme music.

Comment: Sounds like we are looking for the same thing. I recall the cassettes being a distinctive blue colour and white writing. I'm pretty sure there was more than one in the series. I believe I may have one of the tapes but the books are probably long gone...need to go hunting at the weekend.

Comment: I'm also looking out for or just trying to remember maybe the same thing.what sticks in my mind is the noise it made when it prompted you to turn the page like a swoosh.I remember my mum used to buy them and me and my brother would listen and they were quite scary

Answer (score 7):

[Audisee Book & Tape Adventure:  The Lost Ones](http://2-xl.net/?p=958)

Series of 6 adventures was created & sold circa 1978-1981, consisting of a cassette tape with actors, sound effects, and music, plus an illustrated storybook.

*The Lost Ones* adventure tape is a science fiction story about 2 men + 1 alien woman fighting against an evil race of aliens.  In the last battle, one of the men dies fighting off an attack, but the man & woman survive, destroy the evil aliens' world, and land on an uninhabited world where they intend to live out their lives.

Search YouTube for [*Audisee: The Lost Ones*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qDKCTMA-_jo).  Video includes entire recorded story & picture book.

Comment: This is it!  I have been looking for this for ages now.  Thanks a million, this is awesome.  I could remember a few pieces of the story, but the musical score has been in my head for 30 years!  It's just as cool as I remember.  Thanks again!

Comment: @HighWiredSith: If it is indeed a match, please click on the checkmark to accept the answer. ^_^